# Append URLs with #content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to customize a photo gallery in Squarespace.  A test gallery can be found here - http://dzrtgrls.squarespace.com/gallery/test-2/4011897 .  What I would like is to have the next or previous images load so that the prev - / + next navigation is at the top of the browser window.   So it seems I need to somehow append each url with #content so the content div is at the top of the window whenever the previous or next links are used.  Is there a way to do this with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Don't quite get your question. You just need the navigation to be placed at the top of the page?

Comment: No, o.k.w., that would be too easy!  I actually thought of getting rid of my banner for the photo galleries, but I would prefer not to have to do that.  I am going to give Annie's suggestion a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to make the content div scroll so that it's at the top of the page? You can do that with scrollIntoView:

```
document.getElementById('content').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is it, Annie.  Thanks for your help!  I'll see if the Squarespacers can help me implement this.

Comment: Annie - well done understanding the question. All the best, Niki.